# Flask and JSON related

Tags: python, json, flask

I'm studying Flask and now want to dump some data to `json` and `print` a piece of data to the web:

```
@app.route('/home')
def index():
    if 'piece' in session:
        m = session['piece']
        session.clear()

    # online_users = mongo.db.GOOG.find({'date': '2017-02-01'})
    return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/query', methods=['POST'])
def query():
    # stockName = request.form['stockName']
    print(request.json)
    stockName = request.json['stockName']
    stock = mongo.db[stockName]
    m = stock.find({})
    session['piece'] = m.clone()
    mClone = m.clone()
    docs = []
    for doc in m:
        one = json_util.dumps(doc, default=json_util.default)
        docs.append(one)
    docs = json_util.dumps(docs)
    print type(docs)
    s = str(mClone[4][u'high'])
    print s
    return s
```

the output is:

```
{u'stockName': u'GOOG'}
<type 'str'>
838.0
127.0.0.1 - - [11/Apr/2017 00:38:28] "POST /query HTTP/1.1" 500 -
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1994, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
response = self.handle_exception(e)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1615, in full_dispatch_request
return self.finalize_request(rv)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1632, in finalize_request
response = self.process_response(response)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1858, in process_response
self.save_session(ctx.session, response)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 924, in save_session
return self.session_interface.save_session(self, session, response)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 363, in save_session
val = self.get_signing_serializer(app).dumps(dict(session))
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 565, in dumps
payload = want_bytes(self.dump_payload(obj))
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 847, in dump_payload
json = super(URLSafeSerializerMixin, self).dump_payload(obj)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\itsdangerous.py", line 550, in dump_payload
return want_bytes(self.serializer.dumps(obj))
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\sessions.py", line 85, in dumps
return json.dumps(_tag(value), separators=(',', ':'))
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\json.py", line 123, in dumps
rv = _json.dumps(obj, **kwargs)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\__init__.py", line 397, in dumps
**kw).encode(obj)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 291, in encode
chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 373, in iterencode
return _iterencode(o, 0)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\json.py", line 80, in default
return _json.JSONEncoder.default(self, o)
File "G:\Python\Python27\lib\site-packages\simplejson\encoder.py", line 268, in default
raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x035026B0> is not JSON serializable
```

I'm a bit curious about the error. It's like happening between `print s` and `return s`. Or would it be possible that after the post of query, `/home` is loaded again, but in this case, `s` should be returned to my web page.

Comment: Update: whatever I tried to return, it always pop the same error. So it;s not about json, but about Flask .

Answer (score 0):

Solved.
Seems `session` will excute by the end of the function, and m has been iterated, thus error appears.
Don't know if this explains correctly.

Answer (score 0):

At first you need `from flask import jsonify`.

```
print type(docs)
s = str(mClone[4][u'high'])
print s
return jsonify({data: s})
```

here is the flask documentation link with an example:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/patterns/jquery/